# How can I show and hide sub-menu in Header using css? (with example)

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to make a header that contains menu with sub-menu

If the user hovers one of menu in the header, the sub-menu should be opened below of it.

Here is the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-mountain-qz7uyh?file=/src/App.js) I have recreated.

The problem is when one of the menu gets hovered, rest of sub-menu is also appeared as well.

How can I make only one sub-menu opened that belongs to the menu gets hovered using css?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit: just move *overflow:hidden* from the class *.menu* to *.sub-menu*

check my [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ancient-bush-4kgdyc?file=/src/styles.scss)

Comment: I also tried this but when the mouse is out of the menu text, the sub-menu string suddenly dissapeared due to opacity 0

Comment: so what is your goal then? I thought you wanted it to disappear. Or do you want to have it collapsed and not disappear instantly?

Comment: sorry for not being specific. yes that is my goal.

Comment: all good, check my updated answer please

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this sendbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-panna-qhwp2r

You can update your CSS slightly as shown below

```
& .menu {
      overflow: hidden;
      min-width: 100px;
      & .menu-list {
        background: red;
        position: relative;
        & .sub-menu {
          background: skyblue;
          clear: both;
          max-height: 0px;
          transition: max-height 0.4s ease-out;
          display: none;
        }
        &:hover .sub-menu {
          max-height: 240px;
          display: block;
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: this is good but no animation